# Can not override safari's default search in safari app extension?

Tags: swift, macos, safari, safari-app-extension

I am developing safari app extension in Xcode using swift language to take over default search to my site.

I have updated `info.plist` file to inject script.js file in every page as using `SFSafariContentScript`.

I have tried using below code in script.js file to add event to default search box, but its not working(It was working in legacy Safari extension).

```
safari.application.addEventListener("beforeSearch", getSearchText, true);
function getSearchText(e) {
    alert("hi, this is from search box");
}
```

**Does safari app extension have support to adding events to search bar ? Any help on this is appreciated.**

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Did you have any luck with this @kalpesh?

Comment: Anyone has a solution?